# Boost-graph: How can I call depth-first-search() when my graph is using listS as VertexList?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-graph

I'm learning how to use Boost-graph library for a university project. I have a graph where I need to add and remove vertices, so I declared my adjacency list with listS as vertex list. I have a big problem with the call of depth_first_search() function: because of listS, I need to provide a Indexes Property Map, but I don't understand how I need to procedes. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>

struct VertexProperties {
    int value;
};


typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS,            // OutEdgeList
                              boost::listS,            // VertexList
                              boost::bidirectionalS,  // Directed
                              VertexProperties     // VertexProperties
                              >
MyGraph; 

typedef boost::graph_traits<MyGraph>::vertex_descriptor MyVertex;
typedef boost::graph_traits<MyGraph>::edge_descriptor MyEdge;

class dfs_visitor : public boost::default_dfs_visitor {
    public:
        dfs_visitor();
        dfs_visitor(const dfs_visitor& other);
        void initialize_vertex(MyVertex s, MyGraph g);
        void start_vertex(MyVertex s, MyGraph g);
        void discover_vertex(MyVertex s, MyGraph g);
        void finish_vertex(MyVertex s, MyGraph g);
        void examine_edge(MyEdge e, MyGraph g);
        void tree_edge(MyEdge e, MyGraph g);
        void back_edge(MyEdge e, MyGraph g);
        void forward_or_cross_edge(MyEdge e, MyGraph g);
        void finish_edge(MyEdge e, MyGraph g);
};

dfs_visitor::dfs_visitor() {}
dfs_visitor::dfs_visitor(const dfs_visitor& other) {}
void dfs_visitor::initialize_vertex(MyVertex s, MyGraph g){
    std::cout << "Initialize: " << g[s].value << std::endl;
}
void dfs_visitor::start_vertex(MyVertex s, MyGraph g) {
    std::cout << "Start: " << g[s].value << std::endl;   
}
void dfs_visitor::discover_vertex(MyVertex s, MyGraph g) {
    std::cout << "Discover: " << g[s].value << std::endl;   
}
void dfs_visitor::finish_vertex(MyVertex s, MyGraph g) {
    std::cout << "Finished: " << g[s].value << std::endl;   
}
void dfs_visitor::examine_edge(MyEdge e, MyGraph g) {}
void dfs_visitor::tree_edge(MyEdge e, MyGraph g) {}
void dfs_visitor::back_edge(MyEdge e, MyGraph g) {}
void dfs_visitor::forward_or_cross_edge(MyEdge e, MyGraph g) {}
void dfs_visitor::finish_edge(MyEdge e, MyGraph g) {}




int main(){
    MyGraph g{};


    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        MyVertex v = boost::add_vertex(g); 
        g[v].value = i;
    }
    MyGraph::vertex_iterator v, v_end;

    std::tie(v, v_end) = boost::vertices(g);
    auto u = v;
    u++;
    while(v != v_end && u != v_end) {
        boost::add_edge(*u, *v, g);
        u++;
        v++;
    }
    /* INDEX MAP CREATION*/
    typedef std::map<MyVertex, size_t> MyIndexMap;
    MyIndexMap i_map;
    auto ipmap = boost::make_assoc_property_map(i_map);
    std::tie(v, v_end) = boost::vertices(g);
    while(v != v_end) {
        i_map[*v] = i_map.size();
        v++; 
    }

    /* COLOR MAP CREATION */
    typedef std::map<size_t, boost::default_color_type> ColorMap;
    ColorMap c_map;
    auto cpmap = boost::make_assoc_property_map(c_map);
    std::tie(v, v_end) = boost::vertices(g);

    while(v != v_end) {
        c_map[ipmap[*v]] = boost::color_traits<boost::default_color_type>::white();
        v++; 
    }

    dfs_visitor vis{};
    boost::depth_first_search(g, 
                              boost::visitor(vis)), 
                              boost::color_map(cpmap);
                              boost::vertex_index_map(ipmap);
}
```

When I'm going to compile this, this is the output:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp:223,
                 from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::adj_list_any_vertex_pa::bind_<boost::vertex_index_t, boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties>, VertexProperties>’:
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2618:12:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::adj_list_choose_vertex_pa<boost::vertex_index_t, boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties>, VertexProperties>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2755:12:   required from ‘struct boost::adj_list_vertex_property_selector::bind_<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties>, VertexProperties, boost::vertex_index_t>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/properties.hpp:201:12:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties>, boost::vertex_index_t>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/properties.hpp:212:10:   required from ‘struct boost::property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties>, boost::vertex_index_t, void>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp:416:69:   [ skipping 2 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp:605:41:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::map_maker<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties>, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const dfs_visitor>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list>, boost::graph::keywords::tag::color_map, boost::default_color_type>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp:621:7:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Graph, class ArgPack> typename boost::detail::map_maker<Graph, ArgPack, boost::graph::keywords::tag::color_map, boost::default_color_type>::map_type boost::detail::make_property_map_from_arg_pack_gen<boost::graph::keywords::tag::color_map, boost::default_color_type>::operator()<Graph, ArgPack>(const Graph&, const ArgPack&) const [with Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties>; ArgPack = boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const dfs_visitor>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list>]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:337:80:   required from ‘void boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Graph>::operator()(const Graph&, const ArgPack&) const [with ArgPack = boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const dfs_visitor>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list>; Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties>]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:342:5:   required from ‘typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const ArgPack&)>::type boost::graph::depth_first_search_with_named_params(const Param0&, const ArgPack&) [with Param0 = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties>; ArgPack = boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const dfs_visitor>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list>; typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const ArgPack&)>::type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:345:3:   required from ‘typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const typename boost::detail::convert_bgl_params_to_boost_parameter<boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base> >::type&)>::type boost::depth_first_search(const Param0&, const boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base>&) [with Param0 = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties>; P = dfs_visitor; T = boost::graph_visitor_t; R = boost::no_property; typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const typename boost::detail::convert_bgl_params_to_boost_parameter<boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base> >::type&)>::type = void]’
test.cpp:100:50:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2548:29: error: forming reference to void
 2548 |         typedef value_type& reference;
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2549:35: error: forming reference to void
 2549 |         typedef const value_type& const_reference;
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2552:47: error: forming reference to void
 2552 |           <Graph, value_type, reference, Tag> type;
      |                                               ^~~~
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2554:53: error: forming reference to void
 2554 |           <Graph, value_type, const_reference, Tag> const_type;
      |                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp:24,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Graph>::operator()(const Graph&, const ArgPack&) const [with ArgPack = boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const dfs_visitor>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list>; Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties>]’:
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:342:5:   required from ‘typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const ArgPack&)>::type boost::graph::depth_first_search_with_named_params(const Param0&, const ArgPack&) [with Param0 = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties>; ArgPack = boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const dfs_visitor>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list>; typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const ArgPack&)>::type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:345:3:   required from ‘typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const typename boost::detail::convert_bgl_params_to_boost_parameter<boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base> >::type&)>::type boost::depth_first_search(const Param0&, const boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base>&) [with Param0 = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties>; P = dfs_visitor; T = boost::graph_visitor_t; R = boost::no_property; typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const typename boost::detail::convert_bgl_params_to_boost_parameter<boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base> >::type&)>::type = void]’
test.cpp:100:50:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:337:80: error: no match for call to ‘(const boost::detail::make_property_map_from_arg_pack_gen<boost::graph::keywords::tag::color_map, boost::default_color_type>) (const boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties>&, const boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const dfs_visitor>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list>&)’
  337 |                       boost::detail::make_color_map_from_arg_pack(g, arg_pack),
      |                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~

In file included from /usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp:24,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp:621:7: note: candidate: ‘template<class Graph, class ArgPack> typename boost::detail::map_maker<Graph, ArgPack, MapTag, ValueType>::map_type boost::detail::make_property_map_from_arg_pack_gen<MapTag, ValueType>::operator()(const Graph&, const ArgPack&) const [with Graph = Graph; ArgPack = ArgPack; MapTag = boost::graph::keywords::tag::color_map; ValueType = boost::default_color_type]’
  621 |       operator()(const Graph& g, const ArgPack& ap) const {
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp:621:7: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
```

I think this is a kind of template error. Can someone explain me where is the mistake?

Comment: You have a type in forward_or_cross maybe that fixes it. Template errors are hell to understand.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, but it isnt't the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The named parameters are not given correctly. They use [Fluent Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface):

```
boost::depth_first_search(g,
         boost::visitor(vis)
        .vertex_index_map(ipmap)
        .color_map(cpmap));
```

Now, you can simplify the rest of the code significantly.

- classes where eerything is public, can be `struct`
- exercise [Rule Of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) when possible
- visitor member could be marked `const`
- take the graph by const reference to avoid copying the graph on EVERY event
- use c++ type aliases (`using`) instead of legacy `typedef`
- add `VertexProperties` with `add_vertex` at once
- prefer ranges over iterator pairs (e.g. `boost::make_iterator_range`)
- no need to value-initialize `default_color_type`, `std::vector` or `std::map` would already do that

Everything at once: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c7526f5e023bd13)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct VertexProperties {
    int value;
};

using MyGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS,           // OutEdgeList
        boost::listS,          // VertexList
        boost::bidirectionalS, // Directed
        VertexProperties       // VertexProperties
        >;

using MyVertex = boost::graph_traits<MyGraph>::vertex_descriptor;
using MyEdge = boost::graph_traits<MyGraph>::edge_descriptor;

struct dfs_visitor : boost::default_dfs_visitor {
    void initialize_vertex(MyVertex   s, MyGraph const& g) const { std::cout << "Initialize: " << g[s].value << std::endl; }
    void start_vertex(MyVertex        s, MyGraph const& g) const { std::cout << "Start:      " << g[s].value << std::endl; }
    void discover_vertex(MyVertex     s, MyGraph const& g) const { std::cout << "Discover:   " << g[s].value << std::endl; }
    void finish_vertex(MyVertex       s, MyGraph const& g) const { std::cout << "Finished:   " << g[s].value << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    MyGraph g{};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        add_vertex(VertexProperties{i}, g);
    }

    {
        boost::optional<MyVertex> prev;

        for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
            if (prev)
                add_edge(v, *prev, g);
            prev = v;
        }
    }

    /* INDEX MAP CREATION*/
    std::map<MyVertex, size_t> i_map;
    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        i_map.emplace(v, i_map.size());
    }

    auto ipmap = boost::make_assoc_property_map(i_map);

    /* COLOR MAP CREATION */
    std::vector<boost::default_color_type> c_map(num_vertices(g));
    auto cpmap = boost::make_iterator_property_map(c_map.begin(), ipmap);

    dfs_visitor vis{};
    boost::depth_first_search(g,
             boost::visitor(vis)
            .vertex_index_map(ipmap)
            .color_map(cpmap));
}
```

Prints

```
Initialize: 0
Initialize: 1
Initialize: 2
Initialize: 3
Initialize: 4
Initialize: 5
Initialize: 6
Initialize: 7
Initialize: 8
Initialize: 9
Start:      0
Discover:   0
Finished:   0
Start:      1
Discover:   1
Finished:   1
Start:      2
Discover:   2
Finished:   2
Start:      3
Discover:   3
Finished:   3
Start:      4
Discover:   4
Finished:   4
Start:      5
Discover:   5
Finished:   5
Start:      6
Discover:   6
Finished:   6
Start:      7
Discover:   7
Finished:   7
Start:      8
Discover:   8
Finished:   8
Start:      9
Discover:   9
Finished:   9
```

Comment: Thank you very match! I have just a question, can you explain me "add VertexProperties with add_vertex at once"? What's happening with this sentence?

Comment: It's in the line `add_vertex(VertexProperties{i}, g)`. You can also write it as simply `add_vertex({i}, g)`